# Can we open task pane from the dialog window in Office js?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to open task pane from the dialog window in Outlook?

We perform the login operation in the Dialog window, however, by the nature of the add-in the Login is directly prompted from the ribbon. Hence, the user does not realise that there is a task pane where more customizations are possible. We want to open the taskpane post login (without requiring the user to click the icon on ribbon)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.